# Import OpenIntents to use the OI File Manager in an Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, import, file-browser

I want to use the OI File Manager as integrated file browser in my app to search and pick a file.

I could implement the browser with the following command:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Then I took a look at the demo example and there is a problem, if I want to import

```
import org.openintents.intents.FileManagerIntents;
```

I get the following error in Eclipse:

```
The import org.openintents cannot be resolved
```

What is the problem?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import anything.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

The above lines will already call for the installed OI File Manager on the device and run the PICK_FILE action.